# How can I delete unused css lines?

Tags: css

I have a css file which contains 5k lines and 40% of them are unused so I want to delete these lines, I found a plugin which can find these lines but not delete them, I think I need a script to do that, does anyone know how to delete these lines?

Comment: Have you tried anything.

Comment: Can your plugin do the opposite? That is, identify all the CSS rules that are being used? Then you could just rewrite the CSS files including all the rules that are being used, and leave the unused rules out.

Comment: @Dave ,what do u mean the opposite ??                               my css files is 200kb and 40% is unused so i need to delete all unused files,

Comment: What kind of output do you get from your "plugin". Can it output which lines are unused?

Comment: Your question and comment is not entirely clear. Does this plugin you have identify unused CSS rules, or does it identify unused CSS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777192/web-tips-for-improving-speed-of-my-website/11777250#11777250), when you use pageSpeed and Yslow, lot of tools are available for optimise your CSS, Your JS, your HTML....

Minififier was available for CSS, and, I'm Not sure, but I thinks, Yslow have a tools for deleted unused CSS and minify...